# save the data in the database by editing the table info - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a page "EditStudent" that display all absentee's name. This page allows the admin to change their status from absent to present or vice versa, add remarks if needed. The information displayed in the page involved two models.

Namelist model.py: Contains all the students information such as studId, studName and more.

MarkAtt model.py: save all the attended students that were marked during the class. So this model does not save the absentees name.

So to retrieve the absentee's name, i have done a set difference from namelist to MartAtt models.

Ive managed to save all the changes made in the EditStudent page except fr the name.

Namelist models.py:

```
class Namelist(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    studType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    courseType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    VMSAcc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    classGrp = models.ForeignKey('GroupInfo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    null=True)
```

MarkAtt models.py:

```
class MarkAtt(models.Model):
    STATUS=[
        ('Present', "Present"),
        ('Absent', "Absent")
        ]


    studName = models.ForeignKey(Namelist,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    classGrp = models.ForeignKey(GroupInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    currentDate = models.DateField(default=now())
    week = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=100) #100 is present
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, choices=STATUS, default="Present")
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True, default = " ")
```

My Views.py:

```
def AbsentStudent(request, id=None):
    start = None
    end = None
    w = 1
    classGrp = None
    attendance = 0
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    group = GroupInfo.objects.get(id=id)
    q1 = Namelist.objects.filter(classGrp=id).values('name')
    q2 = MarkAtt.objects.all().values('studName__name')
    q3 = q1.difference(q2)
    q4 = Namelist.objects.all()
    q5 = q4|q3


    form_class = studStatus
    form = form_class(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.save(commit=False)
            a.currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
            a.classGrp = group
            a.attendance = attendance
            a.week = w 
            a.studName = q5


            form.save()
            return redirect('editStudStatus',id)
        else:
            form = form = studStatus(request.POST )

    context = { 
    'q4' :  q4,
    'group' : group,
    'form' : form,
    'today' :today,
    'w' :w
    }

    return render(request,'studDetails.html',context, {'form':form})
```

My TEMPLATES:

```
<tbody>
{% for q in q4 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{q.name}}</td>
        <td>{{q.id}}</td>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}    
            <td>{{form.status }}</td>
            <td>{{form.remarks}}</td>
            <td><button type ="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" >Submit</button>
        </form></td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my form:

```
  class studStatus(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = MarkAtt 
        fields = ['status','remarks']
```

The error that ive received from this implementation is:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

[image].

I tried to put the student ID as a hidden file so tht i can save it in the database. but the studid is not showing in the template.

How do i get the studId from a query result that is not saved in the database and match with the Namelist model?

Comment: can you add the studStatus form class to your question? `attname` is a property of a Form Field, maybe there's a problem with the definition

Comment: Edited my code above.

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz Do u have any idea how to save the name? Thank you